# How to access a class Data outside another class

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a property Data  in a class BaseLVItem

```
namespace Spo.Plugins
{



public class BaseLVItem : System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem
   {
      public virtual IBaseObject Data
      {
         get{ return m_data; }
      }
      private IBaseObject m_data = null;
```

we used it properly like shown below in a class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI

```
public class ResourcePolicySystemsLVI : BaseLVItem
    {


    public new IResourcePolicy Data
    {
        get
        {
            return (IResourcePolicy)base.Data;
        }
    }}
```

but when i used in the following class  i am getting error  'System.ComponentModel.StringConverter' does not contain a definition for 'Data'

```
using Spo.Plugins;

   public class ResourcePolicyConverter : StringConverter
   {
       public new IResourcePolicy Data
       {
           get
           {
               return (IResourcePolicy)base.Data;
           }
       }
```

i am not able to implement BaseLVItem class here,Can any body guide me here

Dixon i am implementing like this

```
   public class ResourcePolicyConverter : StringConverter 
   {
      BaseLVItem lvItem = new BaseLVItem();
      IResourcePolicy data = (IResourcePolicy)lvItem.Data;
--------------------
else if ((value == null) && data.AgentVersion != null )  
            {
                return m_nullPolicy;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your class `ResourcePolicyConverter` is inheriting from `StringConverter` rather than `BaseLVItem`.  A typo?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot use the `Data` property in your second example is that `ResourcePolicyConverter` doesn't inherit from `BaseLVItem` and thus, the Data property is not available in the `base`.

You can simply instantiate a new `BaseLVItem` and then access the `Data` property.

```
BaseLVItem lvItem = new BaseLVItem();
IResourcePolicy data = (IResourcePolicy)lvItem.Data;
```

Comment: That's helpful :-) What errors are you getting Ricky. What's happening?

Comment: Three errors getting
No overload for method 'BaseLVItem' takes '0' arguments 
A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or property test.DataModel.TypeConverters.ResourcePolicyConverter.lvItem'
Referenced assembly 'Spo.Controls' does not have a strong name

Comment: Your BaseLVItem will need a constructor to start with. I just notice that you don't have one.

Comment: I can't help but think you're going about this the wrong way though. If your BaseLVItem class is designed to be inherited from, and there's functionality you need from it when not inheriting from it, it doesn't make sense for it to be in that class.